# How to do wireless communication between robots and desktops?

Tags: ros, wireless, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently controlling an autonomous navigating robot (turtlebot2) with the attached pc.
However the attached pc doesn't have enough power to do image processing such as openpose, so I want to use a more powerful machine to control the robot. I'm thinking of using a desktop to do wireless communicate with the  robot.
Thank you in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333399/how-to-do-wireless-communication-between-robots-and-desktops?/) by [vrn_uki](https://answers.ros.org/users/45839/vrn_uki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is an inherently distributed network system. You can run nodes on any computer attached to the network containing your robot as long as the ROS network parameters are setup correctly. See [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) for details of setting this up. As long as the computers have a network connection then you can swap processing nodes between computers as you need.

Is your turtle bot attached to a Wi-Fi network in your current setup? It is common for people to use a laptop or desktop with a wireless network to view sensors and send commands to the robot.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-20**:
In addition to this, you can check the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) on how to run ROS on multiple machines. [This](https://answers.ros.org/question/38694/running-ros-across-multiple-machines/) question also addresses the problem.